# fftw3 inverse transform not work

Tags: c, matlab, transform, fft, fftw

I'm writing a simple code for complex to complex DFT in c with fftw3 library.
i have written a file with input array double data so I can compare with matlab fft function.
I try to execute the reverse transform from transform array but results and first input array are different. this is my results:

```
FFTW3 TRANSFORM WELCOME <<<<<

enter the number (integer) N of samples (Bit: 64) (preferably power of 2):8

SAMPLE INPUT
in[0][0] = -216448918.015237        in[0][1] = 0.000000 
in[1][0] = 948904790.062151         in[1][1] = 0.000000
in[2][0] = 826811206.185300         in[2][1] = 0.000000
in[3][0] = 1868763250.342451        in[3][1] = 0.000000
in[4][0] = 703135606.077152         in[4][1] = 0.000000
in[5][0] = -1989016445.622210       in[5][1] = 0.000000
in[6][0] = 1912963650.704585        in[6][1] = 0.000000
in[7][0] = 811527262.805480         in[7][1] = 0.000000

 Hit enter to continue ... 


 FORWARD TRANSFORM COEFFICIENTS

out[0][0] = 4866640402.539672       out[0][1] = 0.000000
out[1][0] = 410260768.150135        out[1][1] = -1738850319.926936
out[2][0] = -2253088168.827970      out[2][1] = 3720402168.707990
out[3][0] = -2249429816.334913      out[3][1] = -3911155208.965507
out[4][0] = 1586282687.363928       out[4][1] = 0.000000
out[5][0] = -2249429816.334913      out[5][1] = 3911155208.965507
out[6][0] = -2253088168.827970      out[6][1] = -3720402168.707990
out[7][0] = 410260768.150135        out[7][1] = 1738850319.926936
do you want to calculate the inverse-transform? (y/n) 
y


INVERSE TRANSFORM COEFFICIENTS
rev[0][0] = -1731591344.121896      rev[0][1] = 0.000000
rev[1][0] = 7591238320.497208       rev[1][1] = 0.000000
rev[2][0] = 6614489649.482399       rev[2][1] = 0.000000
rev[3][0] = 14950106002.739609      rev[3][1] = 0.000000
rev[4][0] = 5625084848.617215       rev[4][1] = 0.000000
rev[5][0] = -15912131564.977680        rev[5][1] = 0.000000
rev[6][0] = 15303709205.636681      rev[6][1] = 0.000000
rev[7][0] = 6492218102.443840       rev[7][1] = 0.000000
```

As you see 'in' and 'rev' arrays are different but direct transform is correct. I've compared it with matlab and results are the same.
When I execute the inverse transform with matlab I obtain the input array.
What can I do?

this is my c code:

```
#include <fftw3.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define PI 3.141592653589

int main()
{

  fftw_complex *in, *out, *rev;
  int i,f0,A,N;
  char no;  
  FILE *fp;
  fftw_plan p;

  printf("\n\n>>>>> FFTW3 TRANSFORM WELCOME <<<<<");
  printf("\n\n enter the number (integer) N of samples (bit: %ld) (preferably power of 2):",(sizeof(fftw_complex)/2)*8);
  scanf("%d",&N);

  //f0 = 50;
  //A = 1;


  //allocating memory for input & output arrays
  in = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
  out = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);
  rev = (fftw_complex*)fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*N);



  //Opening the data file
  if((fp=fopen("lista_numeri_double.dat","rb"))==NULL)
  {
    printf("\nError reading file\n");
    exit(1);
  }


  printf("\nSAMPLE INPUT");
  //assigning samples read from the file
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    //in[i][0] = A * cos(2*PI*f0*i/N);
    fread(&in[i][0],sizeof(double),1,fp);   
    in[i][1]=0;

    printf("\nin[%d][0] = %f \t\tin[%d][1] = %f",i,in[i][0],i,in[i][1]);
  }


  //plan and execute transform
  p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N,in,out,FFTW_FORWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(p);

  printf("\n\n Hit enter to continue ... \n");
  scanf("%c",&no);


  //print output values 
  printf("\n\nFORWARD TRANSFORM COEFFICIENTS\n");
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    printf("\nout[%d][0] = %f \t\tout[%d][1] = %f",i,out[i][0],i,out[i][1]);
  }

  fftw_destroy_plan(p); 

  printf("\n do you want to calculate the inverse-transform? (y/n)  \n");
  scanf ("%c",&no);

  if(no=='y')
  {

    //plan and execute inverse transform
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d(N,out,rev,FFTW_BACKWARD,FFTW_ESTIMATE);
    fftw_execute(p);

    printf("\n\nINVERSE TRANSFORM COEFFICIENTS\n");
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
    {
      printf("rev[%d][0] = %f \t\trev[%d][1] = %f\n",i,rev[i][0],i,rev[i][1]);
    }

    fftw_destroy_plan(p);           
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The difference between Matlab and FFTW comes with the scaling factor applied to the transform.

Whereas [Matlab's FFT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fft.html) is normalized, the algorithm used by FFTW as described [in FFTW's documentation](http://www.fftw.org/doc/The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT.html#The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT), is not normalized. In other words, the full-circle transform using FFTW (forward followed by backward) scales the result by a factor `N`.

Correspondingly, comparing the `in` and `rev` array shows that `rev` is scaled by consistent factor of 8 (the size `N` of the transform used in your example).

Comment: i thought these days matlab stole `fftw` and incorporated it as their own.  [3] FFTW (http://www.fftw.org)

[4] Frigo, M. and S. G. Johnson, "FFTW: An Adaptive Software Architecture for the FFT,"Proceedings of the International Conference on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing, Vol. 3, 1998, pp. 1381-1384.

Comment: @GAlexander afaik matlab is using a modified version of fftw, which is conveniently scaled for backward compatibility's sake.

Comment: in the pld days fftw would crush the matlab fft so much that no one I knew used matlabs implementation.